# Timed Support Chat In Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a flutter project with payment integration. I am very good at front end side but when it comes to back-end it hurts. Anyways I want to add this functionality in my app.

The user will pay price for the consultant. Once the transaction is done I want to give the user a option to chat with the support team of the app but for only 2 days not more than 2 days after the payment. I am using purely using firebase for CRUD functions but I am stuck on this. I have done this in php with sessions but I can't figure out how can I do it using firebase.

Any detailed help/guidance will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. save user profile inside firestore in a users collection
2. add a boolean field called subscribed which is an indicator for the user payment, and subscriptionDate
3. when the user subscribes, record the dattime
4. every time the user opens your app, first check if he's subscribed or not, then compare the current date with the subscriptionDate
5. if the user passed the previous step, open the chat page
6. you can find many tutorials on google that talks about building chat app using firebase in details